# Craft unable to determine if an update is available?

Tags: error-message, error, updates

I just cloned a production site to run in a local environment to test and make sure the site was compatible with PHP7 in preparation for a production server upgrade. For the most part, it seems to have migrated without any issue, except for when I try to check for updates, I get the error: `Craft is unable to determine if an update is available at this time.` Similarly, the edition button at the bottom of the dashboard gives the error: `Craft is unable to fetch edition info at this time.`

I tried deleting my license key and clearing caches to no avail, but then I checked logs and noticed this error had been showing up:

```
2018/02/26 23:50:58 [error] [application] Error in Craft\Et::phoneHome. Message: [curl] 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to elliott.craftcms.com:443  [url] https://elliott.craftcms.com/actions/elliott/app/checkForUpdates
```

I can’t seem to find any other mention of this issue on StackExchange or elsewhere - any ideas? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: If I were you, I'd check and see if curl is installed and up to date. If you let me know what type of local environment you're using (e.g. macOS/Homebrew/Valet, MAMP, Homestead, Ubuntu, etc.) I can help you figure it out if you don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

There's a 99% chance you're running old version of MAMP that needs to be upgraded.

The host that https://elliott.craftcms.com lives on recently dropped support for TLS 1.0, which what your stack is trying to connect with.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. `2018/03/21 00:52:48 [error] [application] Error in Craft\Et::phoneHome. Message: [curl] 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to elliott.craftcms.com:443  [url] ` I didn't have this issue in January on MAMP Pro 3.5.

Comment: @AndreaDeMers Does updating to the latest MAMP fix it?

Comment: I don't know since I'll be using Homestead in lieu of MAMP.